# Prevent joining of older date records in query based on date of records

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e94b86/6) I created with everything I talk about below but this query will specifically be set to only query records from the same one day e.g. `2017-11-29` so this example should suffice.

> ### I have two data tables
>
> 1. **Batches To Run** (Table1)
>
>    - This is the **value** of the number of batches there are to run
>
>      - For example `2 of 25` where `25` is the value gotten from this table
>
>        - I do not want to see any records with less than a `1` values with  this query
>
>          - I also only want to see records with a `3` value for the `IQuality` field
>
>    [image]
> 2. **Batch Count** (Table2)
>
>    - This is the **value** of the batch number that's run
>
>      - For example `2 of 25` where `2` is the value gotten from this table
>
>        - I do not want to see the zero `0` values with this query
>
>    [image]

When I have only one value for a specific date in the BTR table I always get the expected result (i.e. `1 of 25`, `2 of 25` and so on always).

When there is more than one "batches to run" record set in a day (per the example data) and its value is reset to another valid value but with a different and newer time stamp for the same day,

---

### Question

How do I prevent the joining of the BC records that are older than the newer/current/newest BTR record time stamp wise to prevent invalid results [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e94b86/6) example I provided starts this issue at the records with the `2017-11-29T13:59:59Z` time stamp (`TimeStr`)?

I don't want the older records from the BC table matched to the next/newer/newest time stamp record from the BTR table and want it to move onto the next true record value based on time so when newer BTR record exists, do not look at anything less than that time until another new record.

---

### Raw SQL

**Create Table and Insert Data**

```
CREATE TABLE `batchestorun` (
  `TimeInt` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `TimeStr` datetime NOT NULL,
  `IsInitValue` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IQuality` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_Times` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`)
); 

CREATE TABLE `batchescomplete` (
  `TimeInt` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `TimeStr` datetime NOT NULL,
  `IsInitValue` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IQuality` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_Times` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`)
);

## BTR
INSERT INTO `batchestorun` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511917564','2017-11-29 01:06:04',1,0,0);
INSERT INTO `batchestorun` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511938976','2017-11-29 07:02:56',0,21,3);
INSERT INTO `batchestorun` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511962086','2017-11-29 13:28:06',0,0,3);
INSERT INTO `batchestorun` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511962089','2017-11-29 13:28:09',0,1,3);
INSERT INTO `batchestorun` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511962979','2017-11-29 13:42:59',0,20,3);
INSERT INTO `batchestorun` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511971912','2017-11-29 16:11:52',0,0,3);
INSERT INTO `batchestorun` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511971934','2017-11-29 16:12:14',0,25,3);

## BC
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511917564','2017-11-29 01:06:04',1,0,0);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511939767','2017-11-29 07:16:07',0,1,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511940230','2017-11-29 07:23:50',0,2,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511940692','2017-11-29 07:31:32',0,3,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511942121','2017-11-29 07:55:21',0,4,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511944099','2017-11-29 08:28:19',0,5,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511945511','2017-11-29 08:51:51',0,6,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511947447','2017-11-29 09:24:07',0,7,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511948408','2017-11-29 09:40:08',0,8,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511949620','2017-11-29 10:00:20',0,9,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511951571','2017-11-29 10:32:51',0,10,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511952520','2017-11-29 10:48:40',0,11,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511953011','2017-11-29 10:56:51',0,12,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511953960','2017-11-29 11:12:40',0,13,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511954905','2017-11-29 11:28:25',0,14,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511955860','2017-11-29 11:44:20',0,15,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511956351','2017-11-29 11:52:31',0,16,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511959198','2017-11-29 12:39:58',0,17,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511960194','2017-11-29 12:56:34',0,18,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511960731','2017-11-29 13:05:31',0,19,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511961677','2017-11-29 13:21:17',0,20,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511962086','2017-11-29 13:28:06',0,0,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511962849','2017-11-29 13:40:49',0,1,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511963999','2017-11-29 13:59:59',0,2,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511965321','2017-11-29 14:22:01',0,3,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511971912','2017-11-29 16:11:52',0,0,3);
INSERT INTO `batchescomplete` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1511971935','2017-11-29 16:12:15',0,1,3);
```

**Join Query**

```
SELECT
     IF(btr.TimeStr<= bc.TimeStr, CONCAT(bc.Value," of ",btr.Value), '') Batch
    , bc.TimeStr
FROM BatchesComplete bc
    INNER JOIN BatchesToRun btr ON btr.TimeStr <= bc.TimeStr
    WHERE btr.Value >1 AND bc.Value >0 AND btr.IQuality = 3;

#SELECT * FROM batchestorun;
#SELECT * FROM batchescomplete;   
#SELECT * FROM batchestorun WHERE Value >1;
#SELECT * FROM batchescomplete WHERE Value >0;
```

---

---

### Expected Result Example

So as per the result set in the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e94b86/6) I provided the `Batch` column records going from `1 of 21` on row one to `20 of 21` on row 20 are all correct.

The rows after that which correlate to when the next `BTR` table `Value` field of `20` comes in play, the results show the `2017-11-29 13:59:59` "**BC**" `Value` field with the previous "**BTR**" and the new "**BTR**" both.

---

While that gets both `2 of 20` and `2 of 21` I need it to only show  `2 of 20` for the next/newer "**BTR**" value and not look back and join anything with older records since `TimeStr` of the newest "**BTR**" table `Value` record.

> **Another Expected Result Example**
>
> So after the first 20 records in my example, I want the results to
>   look like this—the closer the better but I can whip something up even
>   if you can help me get something close.
>
> [image]

**Table Relationship**

[image]

Comment: Where I mention "**<#> values with this query**" I am referring to the actual `Value` field in case anyone wonders I wanted to mention that if what I mean record wise for just that field.

Comment: How are the two tables (BC and BTR) linked? Can you show the SQL you are using to join them that is close to what you want?

Comment: @ChrisCarr The tables are joined per the `TimeStr` in the http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e94b86/6 example I provided. There are no keys or anything like that in this case and the relationship is table to table and the data is linked from those tables with the `TimeStr` column conditions.

Comment: @ChrisCarr Additionally, this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e94b86/31 may help you see all the data in the JOIN condition if that's would help. Someone said to use `GROUP BY` then deleted the answer so I tried but it didn't look right and when I went back to check the answer was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. You'll need to do a subselect to retrieve the MAX(timestr) from BTR and use that to do your join. I've rearranged the query a little, but I think this is what you might be after:

```
SELECT bc.value, btr.value, bc.timestr, btr.timestr 
FROM batchescomplete bc,
     batchestorun btr
WHERE btr.timestr = (SELECT MAX(btr2.timestr) FROM batchestorun btr2 WHERE bc.timestr >= btr2.TimeStr and btr2.value > 1 and btr2.IQuality = 3)
    AND bc.value > 0
```

Comment: Appreciate your help with such a simple solution. I made a few small adjustments to the query to get my exact results but you appear to have been spot on regarding the sub-select `WHERE` clause filtering method!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from your "Expected Result Example" visual that you want the rows presented in the following fashion:

```
Green BTR Row
Green BC Rows
Red BTR Row
Red BC Rows
Blue BTR Row
Blue BC Row
```

To do this, you don't actually need to join the tables. Simply apply the desired filtering to each table, smash the two result sets together with a union, and order the rows by TimeStr:

```
SELECT * FROM batchestorun WHERE Value >1
union all
SELECT * FROM batchescomplete WHERE Value >0
order by timestr
```

Results:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e94b86/34

Please let me know if I misunderstood what you want as the desired output.